# Why my iframe treats html content as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Why `iframe` is treating my html content as text content.

**Question:** i want to render whole html with its tags, not as a text.

Below image shows my problem:

[image]

**My code:**

```js
$('#resultBtn').off('click');
 $('#resultBtn').on('click',function(){
 
 var html = '<p id="pclick">Click me to see Alert</p>'
  var javascript = `document.querySelector('#pclick').on('click',function(){
     alert('clicked me');
 })`;
  var bodyContent = html +`<script>${javascript}<\/script>`;


$("#result_iframe").contents().find("body").html(`${bodyContent}`);

});
```

```css
#result_iframe{
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   background:#eaeaed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button id="resultBtn">see Result</button>


<iframe id="result_iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: @terrymorse, full html content like this `<p id="pclick">Click me to see Alert</p><script>document.querySelector('#pclick').on('click',function(){
alert('clicked me');
})</script>`

Comment: That’s not how an iframe works.

Comment: @terrymorse, then how code snippet of stackoverflow,jsfiddle,codepen works, it works with iframe

Comment: i was referring this site to create my own jsfiddle https://websanova.com/posts/jquery/how-to-write-your-own-jsfiddle-in-15-minutes-or-less

its demo is here http://jsnova.websanova.com/

Comment: I'll provide references in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I understand that you cannot pass JS in text after reading the document.
In the editor here it doesn't work, I don't know why, but in a test file it worked.
Try this (JS en parent).

```
  <button id="resultBtn">see Result</button>
   <iframe id="result_iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   <script>
     var button = document.getElementById("resultBtn");
     var iframe = document.getElementById("result_iframe");

     button.onclick = function(){
       iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<p onclick='window.parent.showAlert()'>Click Me</p>"
     }
     function showAlert(){
       alert("Hi");
     }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is attempting to add HTML content to an `iframe`:

```
$("#result_iframe").contents().find("body").html(`${bodyContent}`);
```

However, adding text nodes or HTML elements to an `iframe` is not supported. From the [HTML5 spec for iframe](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-iframe-element):

> 4.8.5 The iframe element
>
> Content model:
>         Nothing

And here's what [Nothing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-content-nothing) means in this context:

> When an element's content model is nothing, the element must contain no Text nodes (other than inter-element whitespace) and no element nodes.

Given that adding content to an `iframe` is not supported, it's probably a good idea to use a different method.

Answer (score -1):

Semed, you codes working fine. Make sure your script was written after jquery insert.

```
$('#resultBtn').off('click');
$('#resultBtn').on('click',function(){
  var html = '<p id="pclick">Click me to see Alert</p>'
  var javascript = `document.querySelector('#pclick').on('click',function(){
alert('clicked me');
})`;
  var bodyContent = html +`<script>${javascript}<\/script>`;


  $("#result_iframe").contents().find("body").html(`${bodyContent}`);
});
```

Comment: can you please provide me a snippet, here or jsfiddle